characteristic points for a vector field
A vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$
$F(x_1,x_2)= \sin(x_2) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+ \frac{-x_1 - \sin x_2}{\cos x_2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$
has a following graphical representation:

A set of particularly interesting points are fixed points (equilibria) given by $x_{eq}=(0,k\pi)$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.
However another interesting points seems to be at singularities, i.e. $x_1=(-1,\frac{pi}{2})$ and $x_2=(1,-\frac{pi}{2})$, since they change repelling/attracting behavior of the singularities.  I mean that to the left of the point $x_2$ the vectors converge to the singularity and to the right they are repelled.
Do these points have a specific name? Is there anything interesting known about them? Can they be calculated?
I would be very grateful for any advice and help.
Regards,
